# Open Sets in Metric Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Munkres asks the following question:

> Let $X$ be a metric space with $d$ as a metric. Show that $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

The solution [here](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-20-the-metric-topology/problem-3-solution/) shows this by taking the preimage of an open set in $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, call it $d^{-1}(U)$, and constructing an open set in the domain that will map back into $d^{-1}(U)$. The conclude the proof here. How can one conclude $d^{-1}(U)$ is open by showing it contains an open ball? Many types of set have open sets in them - for instance a compact interval on the line.

Comment: The chosen point was arbitrary, so they are showing that every point is interior.

Comment: Or, alternatively, that the preimage is a union of open balls, hence open.  It’s the same thing.

Comment: okay, I see that $x' \times y' \in B_d(x,\epsilon/2) \times B_d(y,\epsilon/2)$ is arbitrary in $B_d(x,\epsilon/2) \times B_d(y,\epsilon/2)$. But then they say go on to say $B_d(x,\epsilon/2) \times B_d(y,\epsilon/2) \subset d^{-1}(U)$. How is $B_d(x,\epsilon/2) \times B_d(y,\epsilon/2)$ arbitrary in  $d^{-1}(U)$? $B_d(x,\epsilon/2) \times B_d(y,\epsilon/2) \subset d^{-1}(U)$ can't "move around" to cover $d^{-1}(U)$ its fixed at $x \times y$

Comment: o wait, is $x \times y$ arbitrary in $d^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: Yes, $x \times y$ is arbitrary in $d^{-1}[U]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that proof shows is that for *each* $(x,y)\in d^{-1}(U)$, the set $d^{-1}(U)$ contains a product of open balls centered at $(x,y)$. By the definition of open set on a metric space, this proves that $d^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

In fact for **every** $(x,y) \in d^{-1}[U]$ there are open sets $V_1,V_2$ of $X$ (of the form open balls), such that $(x,y) \in V_1 \times V_2 \subseteq d^{-1}[U]$. This makes $d^{-1}[U]$ an open set in the product topology (as all points are interior points of $d^{-1}[U]$).